# SEVERE: Unable to create initial connections of pool - tomcat 7 with context.xml file

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, runtimeexception

I tried to run project on tomcat `7.0.52` and initialize to DB through `context.xml` file.

But it throws bunch of exceptions, I couldn't figure out what is wrong there.

Here is console output:

```
java.sql.SQLException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:254)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:701)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:635)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:486)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:144)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:116)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:103)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:554)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:242)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:141)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
```

Here is full [stack trace](http://pastebin.com/YxdqUySS).

Here is output to [tomcat catalina log](http://pastebin.com/HqNag3tA)

snippet of **web.xml**:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>Travel Agency Datasource</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/onlinedb</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

**context.xml**:

```
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/onlinedb"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
              maxActive="20" maxIdle="10"
              maxWait="-1"
              username="root"
              password="secret"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/travelagency?characterEncoding=utf8"/>
</Context>
```

**ConnectionManager** class:

```
public class ConnectionManager {
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ConnectionManager.class);

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            Context initContext = new InitialContext();
            Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
            DataSource datasource = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/onlinedb");
            con = datasource.getConnection();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            log.error(e);
        }
        return con;
    }
}
```

`mysql-connector-java-5.1.27-bin.jar` is added to cp:

[image: travel]

I tried to change content of context.xml file:

```
<resource-env-ref>
        <description>Travel Agency Datasource</description>
        <resource-env-ref-name>jdbc/onlinedb</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>javax.sql.DataSource</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>
```

But it keep failing.

***How to solve this trouble?***

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to add a MySQL jdbc driver to the classpath.

Either put a MySQL binary jar to **tomcat lib** folder or add it to we application **WEB-INF/lib** folder.

You can find binary jar (*Change version accordingly*):  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.27

Comment: Try to add it to tomcat lib folder

Answer (score 10):

When you encounter exceptions like this, the most useful information is generally at the bottom of the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
  ...
  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:246)
```

The problem is that Tomcat can't find `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`. This is usually caused by the JAR containing the MySQL driver not being where Tomcat expects to find it (namely in the `webapps/<yourwebapp>/WEB-INF/lib` directory).

Comment: This is the more accurate answer.

Answer (score 3):

I use sprint-boot (2.1.1), and mysql version is 8.0.13. I add dependency in pom, solve my problem.

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.13</version>
 </dependency>
```

MySQL Connector/J » 8.0.13 link:  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.13 
MySQL Connector/J  »  All the version link:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java

Answer (score 2):

I have also dealt with this exception after a fully working context.xml setup was adjusted.  I didn't want environment details in the context.xml, so I took them out and saw this error.  I realized I must fully create this datasource resource in code based on System Property JVM -D args.

Original error with just user/pwd/host removed:
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool init
SEVERE: Unable to create initial connections of pool.

Removed entire contents of context.xml and try this:
Initialize on startup of app server the datasource object sometime before using first connection.  If using Spring this is good to do in an @Configuration bean in @Bean Datasource constructor.

package to use: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.*

```
PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
p.setUrl(jdbcUrl);
            p.setDriverClassName(driverClass);
            p.setUsername(user);
            p.setPassword(pwd);
            p.setJmxEnabled(true);
            p.setTestWhileIdle(false);
            p.setTestOnBorrow(true);
            p.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
            p.setTestOnReturn(false);
            p.setValidationInterval(30000);
            p.setValidationQueryTimeout(100);
            p.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(30000);
            p.setMaxActive(100);
            p.setInitialSize(5);
            p.setMaxWait(10000);
            p.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(60);
            p.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(30000);
            p.setMinIdle(5);
            p.setLogAbandoned(true);
            p.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
            p.setJdbcInterceptors(
              "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;"+
              "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer");
            org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource ds = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();
            ds.setPoolProperties(p);
            return ds;
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: Hi - sorry was working on editing as I found solution before submitting first part.  Can you please revote if you agree this is now helpful.

Comment: I actually wasn't the one who downvoted your answer. However, it's still a little confusing, as you appear to ask a separate question and then answer the original question? If you re-edit to remove your question (which would be better asked as a separate question, imho) I'll upvote to remove the damage done by your downvoter.